# How to embed a modal in a rhandsontable's cell in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, handsontable, rhandsontable

I ask this question because I don't see an exact approach on how to do it. The thing is that I need that for each column, the user can select a function.

In order to make it user-friendly, I want that when I press a cell (that is in each column), a modal opens and allows me to choose a value that will be stored in that cell.

I have no idea on how to exactly do it but so far I've thought in using [Handonstable](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable) with a custom render to create the modal that opens but where I need help, is that I don't know how I will be able there to do the plots and to send the value to be stored in the table.

Any idea, suggestion or approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using DT instead. In handsontable even I've been able to do a custom render to with html do a button, handsontable is limited so it doesn't work :/

So the answer is, you can't do it or if you can, will be a hard job and all hardcoded.

Hope it helps.